# the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 5 tx has nonce of: 15

Tags: ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle

Using truffle (3.4.6), metamask (3.9.2) and testrpc (4.0.1), I call a transaction and get "Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 5 tx has nonce of: 15". I have cut down the body of my contract method to something trivial and I still get this. Any idea what causes it?

```
contract MyContract {
  mapping (address => bool) authorized;

  function myMethod (uint element, uint price) whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
     if (!authorized[msg.sender]) throw;
     return true;
  }
}
```

I call the method like this (using truffle):

```
  MyContract.deployed().then((instance) => {
      instance.myMethod (id, price, {from: account}).then (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this thread](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1127) i saw a suggestion of switching networks back and forth and the error self correcting.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

@okwme is right, but you can also change your configuration of the network to fix the issue. Assume you're running a dev network on localhost with a HDWallet provider, then you can fix the error by commenting out that config property and add host and port properties to it.
It looks like follows:

```
development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 6721975
      // networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
      // provider: function() {
      //   return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'http://127.0.0.1:8545/', 0, 10);
      // },
      // network_id: '*',
      // gas: 6721975,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error using [etherjs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/). As of ethers v6, you can use the [getNonce](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Signer-getNonce) method on your signer to find the Nonce and then pass that Nonce to the deploy method on your contract. Full example:

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    provider
  );

 const nonce = await wallet.getNonce();

const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(
    {   
        nonce: nonce,
        gasLimit: 1000000,
        gasPrice: 2000000000,
        value: 0,
    }
  );
```